# How to find contours in tilted document

Tags: android, opencv

Right now I am using

```
Imgproc.findContours(cannedImage, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

to find the contours and it's working fine when the document is put straight in front of the camera. But it's not detecting tilted document. Any idea how can I find the contours in a tilted document?

This is my complete function:

```
private ArrayList<MatOfPoint> findContours(Mat src) {

        double ratio = src.size().height / 500;
        int height = Double.valueOf(src.size().height / ratio).intValue();
        int width = Double.valueOf(src.size().width / ratio).intValue();
        Size size = new Size(width, height);

        Mat resizedImage = new Mat(size, CvType.CV_8UC4);
        Mat grayImage = new Mat(size, CvType.CV_8UC4);
        Mat cannedImage = new Mat(size, CvType.CV_8UC1);

        Imgproc.resize(src, resizedImage, size);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(resizedImage, grayImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 4);
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(grayImage, grayImage, new Size(5, 5), 0);
        Imgproc.Canny(grayImage, cannedImage, 75, 200);

        ArrayList<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
        Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

        Imgproc.findContours(cannedImage, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        hierarchy.release();

        Collections.sort(contours, new Comparator<MatOfPoint>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(MatOfPoint lhs, MatOfPoint rhs) {
                return Double.valueOf(Imgproc.contourArea(rhs)).compareTo(Imgproc.contourArea(lhs));
            }
        });

        resizedImage.release();
        grayImage.release();
        cannedImage.release();

        return contours;
    }
```

Comment: Share your code, source and result images.

Comment: @Zindarod I had edited my code. Result image is fine. This code is running on the preview frame, not the captured image. And I am kind of detecting edges using contour points.

Comment: Share an image where you're having problems and the desired output.